# Use GUI application on Github Codespace

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, github, user-interface, browser

I recently created a Github Codespace but when I tried to run applications like Firefox, I got this:

`Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`

I guess this is because Github Codespace don't have a buildin GUI.

My home computer's operating system is Windows 11 and my Codespace is a 4 cores, 16 GB RAM, 32 GB storage Ubuntu with only a Vscode as GUI.

I really just want to access web pages and DON'T mention w3m.

I tired to follew [this](https://babyprogrammer.com/blog/running-gui-code-applications-in-github-codespaces-on-windows/) article to solve the problem, but I when I tried to connect to my Codespace via Github CLI, I got this:

`C:\Users\my-user-name>gh cs ssh -- -XY`

`selecting ssh keys: checking configured keys: could not find ssh executable: exec: "ssh": executable file not found in %PATH%`

I find [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/main/script-library/docs/desktop-lite.md) and tried it out, but I don't know if I can't find the .devcontainer folder on my Codespace and basicly don't know what to do.

Can you help? Thank you very much.

Comment: SSH client and X11 server is not part of the default Windows installation.  It's easier to forward the X11 client to your home PC if your home PC runs a Linux distro.

Comment: @Arnie97 thanks for your comment! I'm not very good at this sort of thing and  I don't really know what X11 is. Does it have something to do with applications like MobaXterm? I have MobaXterm installed on my Windows home PC, how should I use it? I ran a Ubuntu VM on my PC and successfully connected the Codespace via CLI, but the GUI is horribly slow and have lots of BUG and basicly unusable. Should I try to run it on a real Linux computer? Thank you very much for you time and effort.